# F# Asp.Net CodeDom ProviderOptions Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis, f#, codedom

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC application using F# on IIS 7.

When I attempt to run it from the browser, I'm met with a YSOD containing the following:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: dictionary]
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IDictionary`2
>   dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1
>   comparer) +12700827
>   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CreateCodeDomProviderWithPropertyOptions(Type
>   codeDomProviderType) +84
>   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CreateCodeDomProviderNonPublic(Type
>   codeDomProviderType) +16
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder..ctor(CompilationSection
>   compConfig, ICollection
>   referencedAssemblies, CompilerType
>   compilerType, String
>   outputAssemblyName) +469
>   System.Web.Compilation.CompilerType.CreateAssemblyBuilder(CompilationSection
>   compConfig, ICollection
>   referencedAssemblies, String
>   generatedFilesDir, String
>   outputAssemblyName) +127
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>   +675    System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>   +46    System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +11321455
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
>   +50    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   +872

I looked up the method using Reflector to see if it could give me any more context and found that it was failing on the first line

```
private static CodeDomProvider CreateCodeDomProviderWithPropertyOptions(Type codeDomProviderType)
{
IDictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>(GetProviderOptions(codeDomProviderType));
//Snip
}
```

It leads me to believe that the propertyOptions I've specified in my Web.config for the F# CodeDom are incorrect. However, if I remove them I receive the same error.

```
<system.codedom>
 <compilers>
  <compiler language="F#;f#;fs;fsharp" extension=".fs" warningLevel="4" 
            type="Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpAspNetCodeProvider, 
                  FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
  </compiler>
 </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Any ideas on correcting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause to the problem.

The Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpAspNetCodeProvider.FileExtension is hardcoded to "fs".

Inside of `System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomCompilationConfiguration..ctor()` CompilerInfos are created for each of the allowed languages. A CompilerInfo for FSharp is not found within the creation of this.

```
internal CodeDomCompilationConfiguration()
{
this._compilerLanguages = new Hashtable(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
this._compilerExtensions = new Hashtable(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
this._allCompilerInfo = new ArrayList();
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.WarningLevel = 4;
string codeDomProviderTypeName = "Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
CompilerInfo compilerInfo = new CompilerInfo(compilerParams, codeDomProviderTypeName);
compilerInfo._compilerLanguages = new string[] { "c#", "cs", "csharp" };
compilerInfo._compilerExtensions = new string[] { ".cs", "cs" };
compilerInfo._providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
compilerInfo._providerOptions["CompilerVersion"] = "v4.0";
this.AddCompilerInfo(compilerInfo);
compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.WarningLevel = 4;
codeDomProviderTypeName = "Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
compilerInfo = new CompilerInfo(compilerParams, codeDomProviderTypeName);
compilerInfo._compilerLanguages = new string[] { "vb", "vbs", "visualbasic", "vbscript" };
compilerInfo._compilerExtensions = new string[] { ".vb", "vb" };
compilerInfo._providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
compilerInfo._providerOptions["CompilerVersion"] = "v4.0";
this.AddCompilerInfo(compilerInfo);
//Snip
}
```

The FileExtension is compared against `_compilerExtensions` in `System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.GetCompilerInfoForExtensionNoThrow` which (in the case of "fs") returns null to `System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.IsDefinedExtension` which will then return false to `System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetProviderOptions` that returns the null that was causing the ArgumentNullException.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @Brian

Comment: Thats pretty bizzare although i'm sure there is a method to the madness of hardcoding extensions.

Answer (score 4):

It’s a bug in ASP.NET in VS2010 Beta2 (it has since been fixed, so will work in next release).  It affects any 3rd party CodeDOM provider, and I don’t believe there is any workaround.

Comment: Any documentation on this bug?

Comment: All I have is internal emails/bug info at Microsoft, dunno if there is e.g. a public-facing Connect bug.  I did find some conversation that says that supplying "CodeDomProvider.FileExtension" might work around it.  I know next to nothing about ASP.Net, but maybe that means something to you?

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning of the FileExtension. I did some digging and found out the usable file extensions are hardcoded and don't include "fs". I've explained in more detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the bug Brian noted can be worked around by specifying some more info in web.config:

```
type="Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpAspNetCodeProvider, 
      FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom,
      Version=1.9.7.8, 
      Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809"
```